# Custom queries on mongodb reactive repository spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Following this [example](https://dev.to/iuriimednikov/how-to-build-custom-queries-with-spring-data-reactive-mongodb-1802) I am trying to create custom queries, using the reactive mongo template.

I have defined the following files

Repository definition

```
@Repository
public interface SimulationRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Simulation, String>, PersSimRepo {

    @Query("{userId : ?0}")
    public Flux<Simulation> findByUserId(String userId);

    @Query("{userId : ?0}")
    public Flux<Simulation> findByUserId(String userId, Pageable pageable);

    public Mono<Long> countByUserId(String userId);

}
```

Custom query interface

```
public interface PersSimRepo {
    Flux<Simulation> aaa(String userId, Sort sort, List<GlobalSimStatus> status);
}
```

Custom query implementation

```
@Slf4j
public class PerSimRepoImpl implements PersSimRepo {

    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public PerSimRepoImpl(ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Simulation> aaa(String userId, Sort sort, List<GlobalSimStatus> status) {

        log.info("status:{}", status);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId).and("status").in(status));

        return mongoTemplate.find(query.with(sort), Simulation.class);
    }

}
```

When I try to start the project I get this exception

Could not create query for public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux it.reply.evtb.repository.specialization.PersSimRepo.aaa(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,java.util.List); Reason: No property 'aaa' found for type 'Simulation'; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: **No property 'aaa' found for type 'Simulation'**

Where Simulation is the object, apparently spring looks for a "aaa" field inside Simulation

This looks like a bug to me, I can't figure out where I am wrong, I use spring boot 2.7.5